# Separating uppercase and lowercase on a string C#

Tags: c#

can someone please suggest a method wherein i can separate uppercase characters and lowercase characters in a string

```
input  : "heLLoWorLd"
output : "heoordLLWL"
```

Comment: Check this link http://www.devcurry.com/2011/03/find-uppercase-words-in-string-using-c.html

Comment: If you are really trying to learn C# you should do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepare one program for you to doing the same:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Input string.
            string mixedCase = "heLLoWorLd";

            // Call ToLower instance method, which returns a new copy.
            string lower = "";
            string uper = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < mixedCase.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(mixedCase[i]))
                    lower = lower + mixedCase[i];
                else
                    uper = uper + mixedCase[i];
            }

            // Display results.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",
                lower,
                uper);
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
heoordLLWL
```

This code will definitely helpful to you.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of few extension methods like the following:

```
string strInput="heLLoWorLd";
string outputStr =String.Join("",strInput.GroupBy(x=>Char.IsLower(x))
                                         .SelectMany(y=>y.ToList()));
```

You can try a working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rkDm0p)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a simple `OrderBy`? Imo `GroupBy` and `SelectMany` is a bit cracking a nut with a sledgehammer

```
string input =    "heLLoWorLd";
string output = string.Concat(input.OrderBy(char.IsUpper)); // heoordLLWL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string input = "heLLoWorLd";
 string output = string.Empty;
 output = String.Concat(input.Where(c => Char.IsLower(c))) + String.Concat(input.Where(c => Char.IsUpper(c))) ;
```

Comment: your sample does not compile!

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "heLLoWorLd";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder upp = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder low = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in input)
{
    if (Char.IsLower(c))
    {
        low.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        if (Char.IsUpper(c))
        {
            upp.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
string output = low.ToString() + upp.ToString();
```

Comment: Why are you iterating the List two times? why not an else case in the first loop?

Comment: @un-lucky yeah right! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

```
string str = "WeLcoMe";
string _upper = string.Empty, _lower = string.Empty;
foreach (var s in str)
{
    if (char.IsUpper(s))
        _upper += s;
    else
        _lower += s; 
}
str = _upper + _lower;
```

Output will be

```
WLMecoe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "heLLoWorLd";
var output = string.Concat(input.GroupBy(char.IsLower).SelectMany(c => c.ToList()));
```